# Exact Target Template Styling Issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template

I'm developing an Exact Target email template for a client, and I'm running into an issue with the content editor. The email template has a specific design, but when I make parts of it into content areas, the content editor ends up overriding all of the styles in the template.

The client specifically wants the template to be fully editable (it's a newsletter template), but also wants it to stay visually consistent. Is there a way of only changing the text in the content area, without affecting the styling? I know that in other email services this is pretty trivial to set up, but I haven't been able to figure this out in Exact Target.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Which content type are you using for your content area?

Comment: Static content is what I was using. The client wants to be able to type in their own content in the email editor. Should I be using a different content type?

Answer (score 2):

My go-to method is to create an HTML only "init" content area in the template and create a series of variables that are referenced in the template.  The client sets the variables and the template renders the email based on the values of the variables.  It can be an effective way to locking down a template, depending on the client's comfort level.

Another option is to create a template that contains 20(ish) content areas, where the client can retrieve pre-defined content areas.  The empty ones just collapse.  I've seen this method used in very flexible responsive email designs.

The WYSIWYG will always cause problems, so I tend to steer the client away from it.